# Why Ubuntu show a message Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock after a cold boot

Tags: 14.04, 16.04

I'm new to Ubuntu and I'm using Ubuntu 16.04, what happen is it freeze so I just use cold boot since I cannot do anything. After reboot I tried to make update and upgrade but shows an error `Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)`. I get this error message sometimes and sometimes I dont. So my question what does this error means and how to avoid it?

Comment: The error means that another process has a lock on that folder `/var/lib/apt/lists`, and if you wait a few minutes you can update. Now to the other matter please run `df -h` and paste it into your post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of settings and packages that will enable automatic updates.  These will result in the lock file existing while they run.  Normally, they only update every day or week, so you may not notice them if you have rebooted before in that time period.

If you want to stay up to date investigate using an auto updater.  They will want to reboot if the kernel is updated.  There will be an option to enable/disable automatically rebooting.  If you don't enable automatic rebooting, you should get a message when you login to a text window.

Answer (score 1):

This is Because Some of your process are still busy with dpkg or apt-get , so you need to free them by following steps:--

## sudo apt-get clean

## sudo apt-get install -f

## sudo apt-get update